# Using partials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am following [this official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#using-partials-to-clean-up-duplication-in-views) to learn about Rails, where a blog is built, and I noticed that it doesn't seem to be complete.

On Point 5.13 "Using partials to clean up duplication in views", it recommends to take the form to create a post and to edit it inside a partial, because both are so similar. It does speak about a small difference about the routes that both forms use, but it says it is a problem that will be explained later

> Everything except for the form_for declaration remained the same. How form_for can figure out the right action and method attributes when building the form will be explained in just a moment. [...]

But I noticed the guide never actually explains how to do this. (Maybe they just forgot...?)

Can someone explain me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the Rails conventions, you won't have to do anything. This is well explained in the documentation (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

> However, further simplification is possible if the record passed to
>   form_for is a resource, i.e. it corresponds to a set of RESTful
>   routes, e.g. defined using the resources method in config/routes.rb.
>   In this case Rails will simply infer the appropriate URL from the
>   record itself.

Basically, you need to:

1. Use `form_for` helper
2. Pass model object to it (instead of a symbol)
3. Have defined resource in `routes.rb` f.i. `resources :posts`

So if you have `form_for(@post)`, Rails will determine which route to use by checking if `@post` is a new record.

If you want a complete example, just create a new rails app and create any scaffold:

`rails g scaffold User name`

You can check that Rails had put a form in a partial: `app/views/users/_form.html.erb`.

If you want to dig deep, check the source code. The interesting part is in [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f96b38394f48d3b3dd62855157efb739dc975fd0/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L445).

```
action, method = object.respond_to?(:persisted?) && object.persisted? ? [:edit, :patch] : [:new, :post]
```

In our example the `@post` is assigned to `object`. Rails is full of such short-cuts, and sometimes the best way of learning about them is looking at the source code. If you know Ruby well, you'll often find source code to be a better explanation that the docs and guides.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
.
.
.
<% end %>
```

When @product is a new record, Rails know about it and uses products_path. However when the @product is existed one, Rails uses product_path(@product).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do a great job of explaining it. If you look up the page at the two versions of the form, one for `new` and one for `edit` you will see they have two different pieces of code after `form_for`, but they are both passing the `@post` variable. In the first case, the variable contains a new, empty, `Post` object.

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
```

In the `edit` version it is looking up the record, putting it in the `@post` variable and passing it to the form.

```
<%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

The final version, the partial, does not have the extra code indicating if it's a `new` action or `edit`. But due to the URL and the action calling the view, Rails knows which code to sub into the form when using a form partial. More "Rails magic".

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```